# Changing ColorTable on Existing Contour Plots

Tags: plotting, color

**Context**

Recently, Bob Sandheinrich [published](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ColorChanger/) a very useful code to change interactively colours of a given plot as follows:

```
  cc = ResourceFunction["ColorChanger"]

  pl= Plot[{Sin[x],Cos[x]},{x,0,2Pi}]
```

[image]

which allows the user to write

```
   pl//cc
```

[image]

But this function does not work e.g. for `ContourPlot`.

---

**Question**

> Would it be possible to extend this function so as to be able to either change each colour, or replace the ColorTable with another one?

---

**Expected features**

- Ideally, one would like to interface to the builtin colour picker

[image]

so that, when applied to

```
 pl2 = ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
 cc//pl2
```

would allow the user to change the sets of contour colours?

This is related to the builtin functions `ImageRecolor` and may make use of `DominantColors`

**Attempt**

I can extract the colors from the contour plot

```
    col = Select[DominantColors[pl], 
       Most[#] != RGBColor[{0., 0., 0.}] &] // Sort;  rr = Thread[
   col -> (ColorData["AvocadoColors"] /@ 
      Subdivide[0, 1, Length[col] - 1])];
rr // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
reColor[colorScheme_String : "Rainbow"] := 
  Module[{cl = ColorData[colorScheme] /@ 
       Subdivide[CountDistinct[Cases[#, _?ColorQ, All]]]}, 
    ReplaceAll[c_?ColorQ :> Last[cl = RotateLeft[cl]]]@#] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
plot = ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   ColorFunction -> "BrightBands", ImageSize -> Medium, ContourStyle -> None];

Row[{plot, reColor[]@plot}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
Row[{plot, reColor["TemperatureMap"]@plot}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
plot2 = ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  Contours -> 35, ImageSize -> Medium, ContourStyle -> None]; 

Row[{plot2, reColor["AvocadoColors"]@plot2}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

#### Update

Using `reColor` with MarcoB's `Manipulate` interface:

```
Manipulate[
 ClickToCopy[reColor[First @ fun] @ Show[plot2, PlotLabel -> First[fun]]], 
 {{fun, {"WL13DefaultDensityGradient"}, "color function"}, 
    ColorData["Gradients"], ListPicker}]
```

[image]

[image]

#### Update 2: Re-coloring plot and legend

```
reColorLegendedPlot[cf_] :=  ReplaceAll[
  Legended[a_, Placed[BarLegend[{_, v_}, rest___], place___]] :> 
   Legended[reColor[cf]@Show[a, PlotLabel -> cf], 
    Placed[BarLegend[{Blend[cf, #] &, v}, rest], place]]]
```

***Examples:***

```
gradientcolors = Prepend["WL13DefaultDensityGradient"] @ ColorData["Gradients"];

labels = Map[Labeled[ColorData[#, "Image"], Style[#, 12], {{Top, Left}}]&]@
   gradientcolors;

Manipulate[ClickToCopy[reColorLegendedPlot[First@fun]@plot2],
 Spacer[10], 
 Style["color function", 14], 
 Spacer[10], 
 Row[{Spacer[10], 
   Control@{{fun, {"WL13DefaultDensityGradient"}, ""}, 
     Thread[gradientcolors -> labels], ListPicker, 
     Appearance -> "Frameless", ImageSize -> {280, 330}}, 
   Spacer[30]}], 
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might want to advertise that reColor works with `plot = Plot3D[{Sin[x^2 + y], Cos[x^2 + y]}, {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]`

Comment: Though sometimes with some unexpected result! `pl = Plot3D[Im[ArcSin[(x + I y)^3]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]]]`

Comment: @chris, I am surprised that it works for any `*Plot` function other than `ContourPlot`.  It would take more work to make `reColor/reColorLegendedPlot` work with (1) arbitrary color function other than the built-in gradient colors with string names, and (2) `*Plot` functions that  style primitives using `VertexColors`.

Answer (score 4):

Something similar could be built with a `Manipulate` interface:

```
Manipulate[
 ClickToCopy[
  ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> fun, ImageSize -> Medium]
 ],
 {
  {fun, Automatic, "color function"},
   ColorData["Gradients"],
   ListPicker
  }
]
```

[image: interface]

Once you have selected your preferred color scheme, the [`ClickToCopy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClickToCopy.html) wrapper allows you to click on the resulting plot within the `Manipulate` to copy it to clipboard, and from there you can then paste it wherever you need it.

Comment: Using @kgrl answer together with yours you can do:

`Manipulate[ClickToCopy[reColor[First@fun]@plot// Evaluate],
 {{fun, {Automatic}, "color function"}, ColorData["Gradients"], 
  ListPicker}]` which addresses exactly my OP. Thanks to both!